# Java Lag when dragging

Tags: java, user-interface, dictionary, drag, lag

My problem is more annoying than it is critical to my next steps, but hopefully the fix is simple. I have a background map made up of many square tiles which can be dragged by the user to expose terrain not able to fit on the screen. The issue is when the user drags fast, the map doesn't keep up and lags behind. If the user moves slowly the map can keep up. I tried looking for methods within `mouseDragged` but couldn't find any that would help. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: *"What would you.."*  It is not related to me - 'for better help sooner' if you'd like 'less help later', don't bother with it. *"..like to see?"*  An SSCCE, though I thought that was obvious.